# How to close entire application when application has more than 2 forms without showing messagebox more than once

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a application using windows forms. The project contains 3 forms: one login form which is the main form and two others which are child forms to the login form.

My problem is when want to close the total application by using `Application.Exit()` in form closing event my messagebox showing the dialog more than once.

1.This code in Login form i.e main form:

```
private void FrmLogIn_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult loginResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this application?","Close",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (loginResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

2.AdminForm closing event which is child form to login form:

```
 private void FrmAdmin_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult loginResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this application?","Close",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (loginResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

3.Billoperations form closing event which is child form to login form:

```
private void FrmBillOperation_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult loginResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this application?","Close",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (loginResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

When i click the close button in any form it will show MessageBox message only once. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all FormClosing methods call a `ApplicationShutdown` function which handles this in a central place. You don't want to copy this code to every new form you create.

In this method you can check a boolean (watch for thread-safety) called for example `IsShuttingDown`. If it's already true, leave the method, otherwise you ask the question and start exiting.

Answer (score 1):

The `FormClosingEventArgs` instance passed to the `FormClosing` event has a [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx) property, which will be set to `CloseReason.ApplicationExit` when the Exit method of the Application class has been invoked: your handlers should check for this condition and if so then take no further action.

```
private void FrmLogIn_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExit)
        return;

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stuart Dukeld I will check and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
if (fc!= null && fc.Count > 0)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < fc.Count; i++)
    {
       if (fc!= null && fc.IsDisposed!= true)
        {
          fc.Dispose();
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sh_interface_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("This will close down the whole application. Confirm?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
          foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (!f.IsDisposed)
                f.Dispose();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Activate();
        }   
    }
```

This will close all forms including the hidden forms and the main form from Application.Run(new something())...Also this method works when invoked in inherited classes while coded in template class Form Closing event.